# Getting value for select from request parameters instead of model object in Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a filters form in HTML that sends filtering instructions with GET request. After filtering my `<select>`s don't load values from passed request parameters but `<input>`s do with their `th:value`. How can I instruct `<select>` to get selected value from URL parameters (passed with GET)? I know I can get values from object in model with `th:field` but that is not what I want to do, the data I want this controls to select is passed in the request.

This is working well for `<input>`:

```
<input th:value="${param.minFee}" placeholder="Min. Fee" class="form-control" type="number" min="0" max="100" step="0.01" id="minFee" name="minFee"/>
```

How can I make this `<select>` obtain its selected value from request params?

```
<select class="form-control" name="payingCurrency" id="payingCurrency">
<option th:value="-1">Any</option>
<option th:each="currency : ${currencies}"
    th:value="${currency}"
    th:text="${currency.name}"></option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

For this you should use `th:selected`.

```
<select class="form-control" name="payingCurrency" id="payingCurrency">
    <option th:value="-1">Any</option>
    <option th:each="currency : ${currencies}"
            th:value="${currency}"
            th:text="${currency.name}"
            th:selected="${param.currency == currency}" />
</select>
```

With the important party being `th:selected="${param.currency == currency}"`. (Where `param.currency` should evaluate to the parameter you are using.)